# Migrating a CodeIgniter site to a different domain and moving the whole thing down one level in directory

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am working on a site, which is built with `CodeIgniter`.

I have never used the framework before...I've learnt a little bit in the last couple days but really cannot solve my problem.

I have downloaded the site and I want to upload it to my own domain so not to make changes to the live site before testing.

the original site is `example.com`.

I want to upload it to `mysites.com/examplesite` (this will be the base - I use this domain for all my clients' test sites).

I have moved all the files and the database is in place.

I have found the database configuration file and have successfully edited it.

I am having trouble getting the site to work, I think it must be because of the site now being down a directory level.

I have edited `$config['base_url']` so that it is correct...I am pretty sure it is correct because I can now reach the homepage where I couldn't before editing that variable. But, i can only reach the homepage - when I click on a link to another page, I get `500 error Internal server error`.

Does anyone have a quick fix for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you uploaded the htaccess and set the RewriteBase

Comment: `500 error Internal server error` when not on the index suggests that there is probably an issue with the rewrite rules in your htaccess file - can you add your htaccess code to your post?

Comment: please check the htaccess and check again that a rewriteBase is there or not. in both case RewriBase will be equal to /foldername(in whch project is)/

Answer (score 0):

Keep this code on your project's root .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /examplesite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```